# Getting the latest record in CodeIgniter using Group_by

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to group by user_id and get the last record.

```
id |     user_id   |      code
---------------------------------------
1          20          12345678
2          22          45678877
3          20          78945642
4          90          45644564
5          20          00000000
```

Here is what I have so far

```
        $this->db->select('id,user_id, code');
        $this->db->from('test');
        $this->db->group_by(user_id);
        $this->db->where('user_id', 20);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

The result to that query is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [user_id] => 20 [code] => 12345678  ) )
```

Desired output

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [user_id] => 20 [code] => 00000000) )
```

I have tried order_by with no luck. `Select MAX('id')` gets me the id of 5 which is what I want, but the content of id 1.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because max is an aggregate function, you cannot use it directly in a where clause.  So you either need to run two separate queries and save the result of the max function, or just get the max from a sub-query.

Add this to your query:

```
$this->db->where('id = (select max(id) from test)', NULL, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Precisely what I was looking to do. I got pretty close. I had $this->db->where('id = (select MAX(id))', NULL, FALSE);
 I missed the 'from test'  value. Once again, thank you for the help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, here's a valid query which satisfies the stated criteria...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM test x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id FROM test WHERE user_id = 20 ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I was looking for the Codeigniter syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, but you should at least start with a valid query

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

`$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
 $this->db->where('user_id', 20);
 $query = $this->db->get('test');
 return $query->result();`